# Syntax highlighting for specific keyword in Atom editor

Tags: coffeescript, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I want to change the syntax for the keyword `$this` in Atom since, by default, it's colored the same as the other variables.

I tried to look through the CoffeeScript files to find where the other keywords are declared, but I could find them.

Does anyone knows how I could do this?

Comment: Which language?

Comment: @MattSchuchard the syntax highlighting is for php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to do it.

Turns out there's a class for the 'this' keyword in atom, so I simply had to add the following CSS to my style.less file and it colored the 'this' keyword in purple-ish.

```
span.syntax--variable.syntax--language.syntax--this.syntax--php {
    color: #be64ff;
}
```

Note that the '$' has its own class inside the '$this' span component, so it will not be colored if the syntax theme you are using defines the color of '$'.